# YouTube API getVideoId is null

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, gdata-api

I upload some video using *Browser-based upload* method. The video is uploaded fine, however I can't manage to fetch this recently uploaded video's id. 
Here's what I did:

```
$vidEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();
...
...
$tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
$tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($vidEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);
$tokenValue = $tokenArray['token'];
$postUrl = $tokenArray['url'];
...
...
posting using cURL...
```

And the problematic code:

```
$state = $vidEntry->getVideoState();
if($state) {
    $video_id = $vidEntry->getVideoId();
} else {
    die("Error");
}
```

And the **$state** here is **NULL**. What's the problem?

BTW according to manual:

> After uploading the video file, the user is redirected to the nexturl
>   specified in your form. If the upload was successful, YouTube appends
>   **id and status parameters to the URL** as shown in the following example:

But I still can't get them (Maybe I'm thinking of the wrong URL?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was just doing a wrong redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In browser-based uploading your code works at the time when video hasn't been uploaded yet. So it is not possible to know the VIDEO_ID at this time.

In order to get the VIDEO_ID you have to look at Id parameter among incoming GET parameters on your landing page.

Landing page have to be provided to youtube as "?nexturl=" parametar in form action link.